# soapUI: multipart/form-data REST request with a file attachment and json object

Tags: json, soapui

I have a endpoint with following method signature

```
@POST
@Path("/procedures/{procedure_number}/ar")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("document") InputStream inputStream,
@FormDataParam("document") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
@FormDataParam("metadata") Metadata metadata,
@PathParam("procedure_number") String procedureNumber){
    System.out.println(metadata.getId());
    //More code here
}
```

I want to call this endpoint using SoapUI 5.2 **Infact i was able to call this endpoint but metadata object received on calling this method is coming null**.

I followed following steps in SoapUI

1. defined parameter procedure_number and set it as template
2. defined parameter document and set value as file:filename.extension
3. Set Media type as multipart/form-data and selected Post QueryString
4. In the attachments selected file filename.extension and set cached selected

**I don't know how to pass json for Metadata through SoapUI 5.2.**

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

1. I created a file with json content for Metadata.
2. Added this file as attachment and set cached true
3. And created parameter metadata whose value i set as file:filenamewithjsoncontent.extension

Thanks